# How to reset Ubuntu 20.04 Login Screen to defalt like this picture

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, login-screen, default, reset

I want to change Login Screen like this picture

[image: screen shot]

Comment: You've tagged Lubuntu which uses `sddm` as it's Display Manager. The easiest fix is switching to GNOME's `gdm3` of course, but `sddm` does allow some configuration, and is covered in the manual https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html   there currently is no GUI config tool, and more details on config are available upstream & other wikis.  Switching to `gdm3` will be quick, but if machine has limited resources the cost may need to be considered (the *hit* will be minimal)

Answer (score 3):

The picture you show is the GDM login manager with the default Ubuntu theme. Make sure this login manager (package: `gdm3`) is installed. You can then make it the default with the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Select the gdm3 display manager.

If the colors are not the Ubuntu theme, change the theme with the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource
```

Comment: I have added `sudo` to the last command, it needs root permissions.

Comment: @N0rbert for sure, thank you!